# How to extract all of the sections in an obj file

Tags: linux, elf, objdump, readelf

I'm working on an X86_64 Ubuntu machine. I know that we can use the command to extract some sections from an obj file.

Saying that I have an obj file, named `main.o`, now I can do things below:

```
me@my-machine:~/tmp$ readelf -S main.o

There are 13 section headers, starting at offset 0x428:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000040
       0000000000000055  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     1
  [ 2] .rela.text        RELA             0000000000000000  00000318
       0000000000000078  0000000000000018   I      11     1     8
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000098
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     4
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000000000  000000a0
       0000000000000004  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     4
  [ 5] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000a0
       0000000000000004  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 6] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000a4
       0000000000000036  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [ 7] .note.GNU-stack   PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000da
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [ 8] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000e0
       0000000000000058  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [ 9] .rela.eh_frame    RELA             0000000000000000  00000390
       0000000000000030  0000000000000018   I      11     8     8
  [10] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  000003c0
       0000000000000061  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [11] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00000138
       0000000000000180  0000000000000018          12    11     8
  [12] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  000002b8
       000000000000005d  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), l (large)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

Then I can extract some sections with the help of the command `objdump`, for example,

```
me@my-machine:~/tmp$ objdump -s -j .data main.o

main.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .data:
 0000 54000000 55000000                    T...U...
```

As we can see, I extract the section `.data` here.

However, if I try to extract another section, it doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
me@my-machine:~/tmp$ objdump -s -j .strtab main.o

main.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

objdump: section '.strtab' mentioned in a -j option, but not found in any input file
```

Why can't the section `.strtab` be extracted? How can I extract this section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't the section .strtab be extracted?

Possibly because of [this bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23947) in binutils.

> How can I extract this section?

Try:

```
readelf -x.strtab main.o
```